# Why is pandas dropping unique rows?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.4

I am trying to use the `drop_duplicates()` function in pandas, but it seems like pandas is destroying unique data:

`example.py`

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
data = data.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
data.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

`test.csv`

```
x,y
3,5
3,5
4,9
6,5
7,0
8,1
0,2
```

`out.csv`

```
x,y
3,5
4,9
6,5
8,1
0,2
```

Now, I would expect pandas to drop the second row `3,5` since it actually is a duplicate. But why is it also dropping `7,0`?? This makes no sense to me. This phenomenon is causing me to lose thousands of lines of unique data when I scale it up. Am I just not understanding something? From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) it says that "by default use all of the columns", which in my mind means "only drop a row if all the columns of one row match all the columns of another row", but clearly this isn't the case.

I am using `Python 3.4` and am not sure if the same thing happens on `Python 2.X`.

Edit:

Also reproducible without using CSV:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'x': [7,6,3,3,4,8,0],'y': [0,6,5,5,9,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['x', 'y'])

print("Before:", df)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print("After:", df)
```

The folks at [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11376) are aware of it now, so until it's fixed I guess the solution is to either use a workaround from the comments or switch to Python 2.7 for the time being.

Comment: You're right, this example works properly in Python 2, but produces *strange* results in Python 3

Comment: @bushmanov Good to know I'm not losing my mind. Maybe I should create an issue in github.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are the `Column` names, then the `data` should be, for example 3 5 not 3,5 as 3 and 5 are in a `row` but in two different `columns`. Can you show how the `dataframe` looks like before you output it to the `csv`?

Comment: What version of pandas?

Comment: If I change the `drop_duplicates()` to `keep='last'`, I lose `6,5` and keep the `7,0`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Pandas 0.17.0 here

Comment: Definitely a bug, it actually works using `pd.read_csv("test.csv",header=None)` and `data.to_csv("out.csv", index=False,header=None)`

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue in 2.7 where drop_duplicates removes similar (but not identical) rows in time series indexed dataframes.

Comment: @Gillespie, I am using Python 3.7 and I am getting a similar problem. Could you find a solution for this issue? I've seen the https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11376 but I did not clearly understand if they solved it.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? This bug affected 0.17.0,  and updating to a newer version should have fixed it, unless they have a regression in the latest one

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely a bug, for the time being a temp fix you could do

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

data = data.drop_duplicates(subset=['x'], keep="first")
```

Sepcifying the `subset` seems to do the trick.

```
   x  y
0  3  5
2  4  9
3  6  5
4  7  0
5  8  1
6  0  2
```